# pentaho bi jpivot error error 0017

Tags: mysql, windows, pentaho

im trying to run my first bi server 5.1

Its running on windows 8.1 (yeah i know) and mysql. Pentaho BI Server

I finally have it running. I have a datasource to my local database but when i try to load the following xml and make a jpivot view i get the error 17 as seen below. I tested the datasource and said it was ok.

XML

```
    <Schema name="New Schema1">
  <Cube name="cubo" visible="true" cache="true" enabled="true">
    <Table name="data_original" alias="">
    </Table>
    <Dimension type="StandardDimension" visible="true" name="Date">
      <Hierarchy name="Date" visible="true" hasAll="true">
        <Level name="date" visible="true" table="data_original" column="date" type="Timestamp" uniqueMembers="false" formatter="MM-dd-yyyy hh:nn:ss">
        </Level>
      </Hierarchy>
    </Dimension>
    <Dimension type="StandardDimension" visible="true" name="Sistema">
      <Hierarchy name="Sistema" visible="true" hasAll="true">
        <Level name="Sistema" visible="true" table="data_original" column="sistema" type="String" uniqueMembers="false">
        </Level>
      </Hierarchy>
    </Dimension>
    <Dimension type="StandardDimension" visible="true" name="Programa">
      <Hierarchy name="Programa" visible="true" hasAll="true">
        <Level name="Programa" visible="true" table="data_original" column="programa" type="String" uniqueMembers="false">
        </Level>
      </Hierarchy>
    </Dimension>
    <Measure name="Uso" column="uso" datatype="Numeric" aggregator="sum" visible="true">
    </Measure>
  </Cube>
</Schema>
```

Any help would be appreciated

> 2014-09-05 18:06:29,640 ERROR [org.pentaho.platform.engine.services.solution.SolutionEngine] e2c7f50e-3548-11e4-8c84-a01d48b1d73d:SOLUTION-ENGINE:default.xjpivot: Action Sequence execution failed, see details below
> | Error Time: viernes 5 de septiembre de 2014 18H06' CLT
> | Session ID: admin
> | Instance Id: e2c7f50e-3548-11e4-8c84-a01d48b1d73d
> | Action Sequence: 
> | Execution Stack:
> EXECUTING ACTION: Pivot View (PivotViewComponent)
> | Action Class: PivotViewComponent
> | Action Desc: Pivot View
> | Loop Index: 0
> Stack Trace:org.pentaho.platform.api.engine.ActionExecutionException: RuntimeContext.ERROR_0017 - [es_18] Activity failed to execute 
>     at org.pentaho.platform.engine.services.runtime.RuntimeContext.executeComponent(RuntimeContext.java:1211)
>     at org.pentaho.platform.engine.services.runtime.RuntimeContext.executeAction(RuntimeContext.java:1151)
>     at org.pentaho.platform.engine.services.runtime.RuntimeContext.performActions(RuntimeContext.java:1063)
>     at org.pentaho.platform.engine.services.runtime.RuntimeContext.executeLoop(RuntimeContext.java:1013)
>     at org.pentaho.platform.engine.services.runtime.RuntimeContext.executeSequence(RuntimeContext.java:895)
>     at org.pentaho.platform.engine.services.runtime.RuntimeContext.executeSequence(RuntimeContext.java:797)
>     at org.pentaho.platform.engine.services.solution.SolutionEngine.executeInternal(SolutionEngine.java:352)
>     at org.pentaho.platform.engine.services.solution.SolutionEngine.execute(SolutionEngine.java:282)
>     at org.pentaho.platform.engine.services.solution.SolutionEngine.execute(SolutionEngine.java:188)
>     at org.pentaho.jpivot.AnalysisViewService.getNewAnalysisViewRuntime(AnalysisViewService.java:553)
>     at org.pentaho.jpivot.Pivot_jsp._jspService(Pivot_jsp.java:472)
>     at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
>     at org.pentaho.platform.web.servlet.PluginDispatchServlet.service(PluginDispatchServlet.java:89)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at org.pentaho.platform.web.http.filters.PentahoWebContextFilter.doFilter(PentahoWebContextFilter.java:185)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at org.pentaho.platform.web.http.filters.PentahoRequestContextFilter.doFilter(PentahoRequestContextFilter.java:87)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:378)
>     at org.springframework.security.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
>     at org.springframework.security.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
>     at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
>     at org.springframework.security.ui.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilterHttp(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:101)
>     at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
>     at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
>     at org.springframework.security.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:105)
>     at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
>     at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
>     at org.springframework.security.ui.basicauth.BasicProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(BasicProcessingFilter.java:174)
>     at org.pentaho.platform.web.http.security.PentahoBasicProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(PentahoBasicProcessingFilter.java:115)
>     at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
>     at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
>     at org.springframework.security.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilterHttp(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:235)
>     at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
>     at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
>     at org.pentaho.platform.web.http.filters.HttpSessionPentahoSessionIntegrationFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionPentahoSessionIntegrationFilter.java:263)
>     at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
>     at org.springframework.security.wrapper.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilterHttp(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:91)
>     at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
>     at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
>     at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:175)
>     at org.springframework.security.util.FilterToBeanProxy.doFilter(FilterToBeanProxy.java:99)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at org.pentaho.platform.web.http.filters.SystemStatusFilter.doFilter(SystemStatusFilter.java:55)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at org.pentaho.platform.web.http.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:114)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at org.pentaho.platform.web.http.filters.WebappRootForwardingFilter.doFilter(WebappRootForwardingFilter.java:70)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at org.pentaho.platform.web.http.filters.PentahoPathDecodingFilter.doFilter(PentahoPathDecodingFilter.java:33)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
>     at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:470)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
>     at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
>     at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
>     at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:879)
>     at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:617)
>     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:1774)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

.
.

**update:**
added the following

system/simple-jndi/jdbc.properties

```
local/type=javax.sql.DataSource
local/driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
local/url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/local
local/user=********
local/password=********
```

tomcat/conf/context.xml

```
<Resource name="jdbc/local" 
auth="Container" 
type="javax.sql.DataSource"
maxActive="100" 
maxIdle="30"
maxWait="10000" 
username="**********" 
password="********" 
driverClassName="org.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/base_url"  (base_url is not the name, just used it for security issues
/>
```

Comment: also checked http://infocenter.pentaho.com/help/index.jsp?topic=%2Fconfig_ba_server%2Ftask_adding_jndi_data_source.html

Answer (score 0):

Did you write the XML manually? or did you use Pentaho Schema Workbench (PSW)? Sometimes is useful to use PSW and validate the schema. Also, for Dates use the type="TimeDimension"

Comment: hi! i did use the pentaho schema workbench. the schema validated it. im gonna change de date type. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your table references in the schema are not correc: Hierarchy elements require a Table element as a child if they refer to a table other than the fact table;

The table attribute on Levels is not required, unless your table element of the hierarchy is in fact a table join, using more than one table and you need to specify which table to read the element from.

check out the documentation at http://mondrian.pentaho.com/documentation/schema.php

Comment: thanks! did what it said in the documentation. but i still get the same error. getting stumped.